# Why is my apache2 webserver not responding to curl requests

Tags: php, curl, apache2, http-error

I have been trying to use Google Pagespeed Insights API in PHP using php-curl, and sending requests to a `.html` web page I created on my local server. Suppose my IP address is `123.456.78.90`; so here is my script:

```
$url = "http://123.456.78.90/webproject/test/some.html";
//$url = "https://developers.google.com";

$curl_init = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$url&screenshot=true&key=***********");
curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$response = curl_exec($curl_init);
curl_close($curl_init);
$googlepsdata = json_decode($response, true);
echo "response: "; print_r($googlepsdata); echo "<br><br><br>";//check
```

Here is the response:

```
response: Array ( [error] => Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain] => lighthouse [reason] => lighthouseError [message] => Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED) ) ) [code] => 500 [message] => Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED) ) )
```

***WHAT I TRIED:***

1. But when I change the value of `$url` to `https://developers.google.com`, I get a proper JSON response.
2. So I tried to use curl utility in ubuntu from terminal, and executed
   **`curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={http://123.456.78.90/webproject/test/some.html}&screenshot=true&key=**********`** but still got

```
        sn@ubuntu:~$ curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={http://123.456.78.90/webproject/test/some.html}&screenshot=true&key=AIzaSyCvLhgU6dByk_eDRV3FCg4g66oVONau2-8
        [1] 3987
        [2] 3988
        sn@ubuntu:~$ {
         "error": {
          "errors": [
           {
            "domain": "lighthouse",
            "reason": "lighthouseError",
            "message": "Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST.
    Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the
    page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and
    that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details:
    net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)"
           }
          ],
          "code": 500,
          "message": "Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST.
    Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the
    page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and
    that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details:
    net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)"
         }
        }
```

Comment: You need to single quote the URL in terminal.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Did that. Still getting the same error